# How to Build libspotify examples on a Mac

Tags: build, makefile, spotify

I just downloaded libspotify for the mac and I'm attempting to take a look at the examples, but upon Make-ing I get the following:

```
for a in jukebox spshell; do make -C $a  all; done
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
Failed to find libspotify using pkg-config(1)
make[1]: *** [check-libspotify] Error 1
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
Failed to find libspotify using pkg-config(1)
make[1]: *** [check-libspotify] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The documentation on the site seems pretty bare and I don't see anything that addresses the problem im having.  Has anyone had luck using this API on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

The most current set of examples for libspotify on Mac is CocoaLibSpotify, which includes an Objective-C wrapper and an Xcode project that neatly builds and bundles everything together:

https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but try copying the 'libspotify.framework' folder to /Library/Frameworks.

Failing that, try installing libspotify using Homebrew, which will create the necessary symlinks.

[Link](https://brew.sh/)

After installation, run: $ brew install libspotify

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly comprehensive wiki file on github: https://github.com/Burgestrand/spotify/wiki